# Is it possible to run Python embedded in Arduino?

Tags: python

I know how to program in C but I'm more productive in python, so, I would like to know if there is a way to run a python code into arduino.

Comment: http://playground.arduino.cc/CommonTopics/PyMite

Comment: The whole concept just makes me break out in a cold sweat and rock quietly in the corner...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use other kind of board called [MicroPython](https://micropython.org)

But yes, is possible using some kind of TX-RX Python class...